# Performance with @MapResult in spring-data-neo4j

Tags: performance, rest, neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

I am using `spring-data-neo4j` to access standalone Neo4J server via REST api. Severe performance issues are observed while retrieving objects via spring repository using `@MapResult` to transform the retrieved objects list.

Firstly, I observed in server logs (*http.log*) that when we start iterating or calling getter/setters on the retrieved `@MapResult` interface, numerous REST requests are fired in background. In one case it fired 1900+ rest requests while iterating and accessing a list of 5 `@MapResult` objects taking more than 6 seconds when Neo4J server is running on same machine.

I reduced the problem to fetching a single simple relationship which looks as below. I can see in the Neo4J server logs that 9 http requests are fired to fetch this single object when I call *MyMapResultInterface.getRoute()*. **Are these many number of http requests expected/by design? Or am I missing something?** I could find very less documentation on usage of `@MapResult` and its implications.

Relationship model:

```
@RelationshipEntity(type="ROUTE")
@TypeAlias("Route")
public class Route {

    @GraphId 
    private Long id;

    @StartNode
    private Location startAt;

    @EndNode
    private Location endAt;

    private String routeName;
    private String city;
    private long distance;
    private Date createdOn;
}
```

Logs as seen in *http.log* when I call *MyMapResultInterface.getRoute()* :

```
GET /db/data/relationship/28 HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "-" "neo4j-rest-graphdb/1.8.RC2
GET /db/data/relationship/28 HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "-" "neo4j-rest-graphdb/1.8.RC2
GET /db/data/relationship/28 HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "-" "neo4j-rest-graphdb/1.8.RC2
GET /db/data/relationship/28 HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "-" "neo4j-rest-graphdb/1.8.RC2
GET /db/data/relationship/28 HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "-" "neo4j-rest-graphdb/1.8.RC2
GET /db/data/relationship/28 HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "-" "neo4j-rest-graphdb/1.8.RC2
GET /db/data/node/13/properties HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "-" "neo4j-rest-graphdb/1.8.RC2
GET /db/data/relationship/28 HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "-" "neo4j-rest-graphdb/1.8.RC2
GET /db/data/node/25/properties HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "-" "neo4j-rest-graphdb/1.8.RC2
```

Many duplicate *GETs* can be seen above. Just an interpretation, looks like the number of *GETs* on `/db/data/relationship/28` are equal to total number of fields in the object *Route* and there are two *GET* requests for `/db/data/node/{nodeId}/properties` probably for the `@StartNode` and `@EndNode` fields.

**Edit:**
Further to my observations, I noticed that this is not only the problem with `@MapResult` but also a problem with simply mapped results from repository methods, example below

```
Iterable<Route> routes = routeRepository.getAvailableRoutesForUser(user.getId());
```

Even this fires numerous http rest requests to the neo4j server.

**Update:**

As suggested by Michael Hunger in the answer, those would be the two approaches which can improve performance with Neo4j REST api. However, that leads to very large complicated cypher queries and an unmanagable and difficult to maintain code.

Hence, **finally after evaluating all the approaches, we decided to do away with Neo4j REST interface and started using Neo4j embedded.** And that Neo4j embedded is not available with Heroku we had to do away with Heroku. We migrated our application to Amazon AWS.

We hope Neo4j comes up with a remote access channel with performance acceptable in production environments as early as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good point, in general SDN's object representations are not yet optimized for Neo4j server REST interactions. This will change in the Next major version using Neo4j's binary protocol and cypher.

Could you test just returning the information you're interested in from Cypher and

1. reading that directly from `Result<Map<String,Object>>` as method return type and
2. from a `MapResult` that only exposes these primitive types.

Comment: Thanks Michael. Will test with your suggested approaches.

Comment: These approaches lead to complex and difficult to maintain cypher queries. So we decided to use Neo4j embedded instead of REST. That made us do away with Heroku and move to Amazon AWS. Updated the question to include this update.

Comment: @Gopi, using an embedded instance speeds things up, but it still does that many requests internally, right?  i.e.  Using an embedded instance only masks the problem of lots of requests to load a subgraph.

Comment: @Ryan I think yes. But it should not impact performance as those are in-memory calls. At the end, this logic must be executed somewhere right?