# neo4j template slow persistence when dealing with bidirectional relationships

Tags: java, performance, neo4j

Given the following two objects:

```
@NodeEntity  
class Foo  
{
   @GraphId   
   long id;  
   @RelatedTo(Bar.class,direction=Direction.BOTH, type="BAR")  
   Set<Bar> bars= new HashSet<Bar>();    
   @Indexed  
   String name;
}
```

and

```
@NodeEntity  
class Bar
{
   @GraphId   
   long id;  
   @RelatedTo(Foo.class,direction=Direction.BOTH, type="Foo")  
   Set<Foo> foos= new HashSet<Foo>();    
   @Indexed  
   String name;
}
```

The following persistence level code is dreadfully slow (5-20 seconds per persist slow)

```
@Service  
class Persister  
{  
   @Autowired  
   Neo4JTemplate template;    
   @Autowired  
   FooRepository fooRepo;    
   @Autowired  
   BarRepository barRepo;  
void go()  
{  
    Bar bar = barRepo.findByName("myBar");  
    if(null != bar)  
    {    
        bar.getFoos().addAll(fooRepo.readAll());    
        return bar;  
    }
     template.save(bar);  
 }    
}

interface BarRepository extends Repository<Bar>  
{  
     Bar findByName(String name);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Neo4j REST interface? If so, my this post may provide a clue -[Performance with @MapResult in spring-data-neo4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15609074/performance-with-mapresult-in-spring-data-neo4j)

Comment: No, I am not using the REST interface to the best of my knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

How many foo's are you adding to `bar`?

Are you using simple mapping or advanced mapping?

You should have a `@Transactional` around your `go()` method, otherwise there will be thousands of small transactions created for each entity added. (in advanced mode, in simple mode that code doesn't save the changes.)

Comment: Some number between `1-100000`, which sounds really arbitrary but I have yet to notice a performance issue on retrieval.  I will try the `Transactional` tag to see if this improves the performance because as it stands it does look like it is flushing the buffer constantly.  Quick side note, advanced mode vs simple mode is?